# Why can't I click this sign in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Following this tutorial to try and make a button that moves you to the next site in 360 virtual tour what am I doing wrong how come my button I can't Click to go to the next site?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_zUFaqjVZA&list=PLGq_ojdWrNDuVufCMV81d6KmOUfJzc66l&index=16

[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TourManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    //list of sites
    public GameObject[] objSites;
    //main menu
    public GameObject canvasMainMenu;
    //should the camera move
    public bool isCameraMove = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        ReturnToMenu();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(isCameraMove) 
        { 
        
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
            {
                ReturnToMenu();
            }

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
            { 
                 RaycastHit hit;
                 Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100.0f))
                {
                    if(hit.transform.gameObject.tag == "Sound")
                    {
                        hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<MediaAudio>().PlayAudio();
                    }
                    else if (hit.transform.gameObject.tag == "Image")
                    {
                        hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<MediaImage>().ShowImage();
                    }
                    else if (hit.transform.gameObject.tag == "NextSite")
                    {
                        LoadSite(hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<NextSite>().GetSiteToLoad());
                    }
                }
            
            }   
        }
    }

    public void LoadSite(int siteNumber)
    {
        //show site
        objSites[siteNumber].SetActive(true);
        //hide m
        {
            //hide sites
            for (int i = 0; i < objSites.Length; i++)
            {
                objSites[i].SetActive(false);

            }
            //show site
            objSites[siteNumber].SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log($"found site {objSites[siteNumber].name} with {siteNumber}");
            canvasMainMenu.SetActive(true);
            //eable the camera
            isCameraMove = true;
        }
        canvasMainMenu.SetActive(true);
        //enable the camera
        isCameraMove = true;
        GetComponent<CameraController>().ResetCamera();
    }

    public void ReturnToMenu()
    {
        
        //show menu
        canvasMainMenu.SetActive(true);
        //hide sites
        for (int i = 0; i < objSites.Length; i++)
        {
            objSites[i].SetActive(false);

        }

        //disable the camera
        isCameraMove = false; 

    }

    public void ReturnToSite()
    { 
        isCameraMove = true;
    }
    
    public void OpenMedia()
    {
        isCameraMove = false;
    }

}
```

I haven't tried anything because I don't really know what to even try

Comment: do you have an eventsystem? is the button click firing? I mean, not gonna watch some tutorial when maybe yours doesnt work and theres does not going to play guess what you did wrong compared to them

Comment: Do your "Buttons" have 3D colliders? o.O otherwise your `Physics.Raycast` will of course not hit anything ... are they tagged correctly? Is `isCameraMove` even `true` while your are trying to click?